# Navigating through go_router, it's not rebuilding screen every time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-go-router

I'm navigating through go router in my web app. But I'm having issue while changing the screen is that when I open particular screen for the first time then its building whole screen with InitState() but after going to another screen, I'm clicking on that screen again then it's not rebuilding(means not running initState()). I've attached my code snippets as well.

```
final routerProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  final loggedInState = ref.read(isLoggedInProvider);
  return GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: loggedInState,
    routes: [
      HomeRoute(), // /
      PeopleRoute(), //   /people
      LoginRoute(),
    ],
    redirect: (state) {
      // if the user is not logged in, they need to login
      final loggedIn = loggedInState.value;
      final loggingIn = state.subloc == '/login';
      if (!loggedIn) return loggingIn ? null : '/login';

      // if the user is logged in but still on the login page, send them to
      // the home page
      if (loggingIn) return '/';

      // no need to redirect at all
      return null;
    },
  );
});

class HomeRoute extends GoRoute {
  HomeRoute()
      : super(
          path: '/',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: HomeScreen(),
          ),
        );
}

class LoginRoute extends GoRoute {
  LoginRoute()
      : super(
          path: '/login',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: LoginScreen(),
          ),
        );
}

class PeopleRoute extends GoRoute {
  PeopleRoute()
      : super(
          path: '/people',
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
            child: PeopleLandingScreen(),
          ),
        );
}
```

Navigation Code.

```
context.go('/people');
```

**Your help will be appreciated.**

Comment: Can you try `goNamed`

Comment: can you share any example?

Comment: try replacing `context.goNamed ('people');`, include name on `super`>> route, I am not sure, it will replace the path, so hopes it will recall everything

Comment: @YeasinSheikh replacing `go` with `goNamed` doesn't work for me. It was working fine for me with `go_router: 3.x.x` but doesn't work when I updated it to `5.x.x`. Are you aware of any change in its behavior?

Comment: Came across this issue that may be related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116651. Perhaps the people route is not refreshing as you're expecting it to